Topological Properties of Subsets of $R^{m}$ induced by Smooth Manifolds in Matrix Spaces
We know that $M_{m \times n } $ is isomorphic to $R^{mn}$. Let's take a smooth manifold $\mathbb{M}$ in $R^{mn}$ and fix a point in $R^{n}$, say, $p$. Now realize the manifold $\mathbb{M}$ as a subset of $M_{m \times n}$. Let each matrix in the subset so realized act on $p$, and we get a subset of $R^{m}$. So, what can be said about this subset of $R^{m}$. Is this always a manifold? How does it's topological properties depend on $p$ and the initially chosen smooth manifold $\mathbb{M}$, can we find some invariant topological properties which are preserved under some conditions from $\mathbb{M}$ and the newly found subset of $R^{m}$
Some idea
We can think of the manifold acting on $p$ as a linear map associated with $p$ acting on the manifold and mapping it to a lower-dimensional Euclidean space. So in essence what we have is a linear mapping of a manifold, and we are interested in investigation of is there anything interesting happening when we change the linear map induced by $p$ or when we alter the choice of manifold $M$.
Background
I read Loring Tu's "Introduction to smooth manifolds" for my MS thesis. " but I hadn't covered Cohomology of smooth manifolds well. I am not able to "use" the theory I read so far. Would you suggest a way to think about the above problem? Some sort of hint to start with?
Currently, I am not enrolled in a PhD program, for a year, I have to do some project or independent study, I was thinking of delving into the above problem deeply and maybe publishing.
Any references or any suggestions in general will be very much appreciated.

I'd start by reading about smooth group actions, stabilizers, the principal orbit types of Lie group actions, etc.  Generally the answer to your question is going to be no, but there's certainly some reasonable conditions for the answer to be yes.  Tommo tom Dieck's book on Transformation Groups would certainly help.

@RyanBudney Thanks a lot sir for the response. Could you suggest what are the prereq for the book, will the algebraic topology at the level of munkers and differential geometry at the level of Loring Tu be enough to dive in the book you suggested?

A first course on manifold theory, a course on group theory and a first course on algebraic topology is enough to get you started.  As you get further into the book the prerequisites grow but you'll get there when you need to.

Let me write $\mathbb M\cdot p$ for the set $\{Mp,M\in\mathbb M\}\subset\mathbb R^m$. Clearly it is a linear image of a manifold, which already gives you some amount of information. However, it may not be a manifold; for instance, if $\gamma$ is any smooth curve in the plane, then the set of $2\times2$ matrices of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}\gamma_1(t) & t \\ \gamma_2(t) & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
is a manifold (as the image of a proper, smooth, injective immersion). However, for this $\mathbb M$ and $p=(1,0)$, we clearly have $\mathbb M\cdot p=\operatorname{im}\gamma$, so it is a manifold if and only if the image of $\gamma$ is, which may not be the case (say for $\gamma(t)=(1-t^2,t^3-t)$ for instance).
